# NSDateFormatter Daylight Savings Time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using NSDate formatter to take a date in from a Facebook Graph API request (which is in GMT) and convert it to the local time zone of the user. I can read in the date fine and set its new time zone fine, but when I print out the new date, it does not seem to consider daylight savings time.

time below will actually come from the request but for example here I just enter in a standard time string from the Facebook response

```
NSString *time = @"2012-04-12T15:25:09+0000"
NSTimeZone *localZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:localZone];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:time];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateStr);
```

When it prints this date it prints out "Thu Jan 12, 2012 10:25 AM" which for "America/New_York" time zone,  which is where I am, that is wrong. I should be "Thu Jan 12, 2012 11:25 AM" or one hour ahead. Is there a way to force day light savings time? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I noticed that it is actually formatting the month incorrectly. It is taking April and making it January for some reason. Why would this be?

Comment: I just noticed that the month is wrong too. why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When it prints this date it prints out "Thu Jan 12, 2012 10:25 AM" which for "America/New_York" time zone, which is where I am, that is wrong.

Nope. Daylight savings time doesn't start until March, so it would be wrong to apply it for that time. `NSDateFormatter` is doing the right thing here.

If you want to force a specific GMT offset, you should use `NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:` instead of `localTimeZone`.

Comment: Okay well, actually I notice that the whole problem is probably stemming from it formatting the month incorrectly. Any idea why it is getting the month wrong?

Comment: `[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];` should be `[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];`

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks yuji! Gave you a +1 for giving the correct format. I feel like I'm reading greek when trying to decode the markup language document, and converting a random incoming format for it!